# How to clean two databases after running JUnit test method using Flyway

Tags: spring, flyway

I have a JUnit test method which makes call to two different services and both services are running with different data sources and of course in two transaction managers.

So i have configured Flyway to use H2 data base and implemented JUnit test method as below.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class DataControllerTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void testDataSave() throws Exception {
      // test code to call controller  which internally calls two services.
assertEquals(1, JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(this.jdbcTemplate, "Database1Table1"));
assertEquals(1, JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(this.anotherjdbcTemplate, "Database2Table1"));
}
}
```

So my question is this test method is creating some records in H2 database and i want to clear that data after running this test.

```
 <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

and other transaction manager to work on different data source are configured as below.

```
<bean id="txManager2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="anotherDataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Since i gave this test class as Transactional it would clean database after each test method run.
But currently it is clearning only one database. but i want to clean another database which is part of anotherDatasource.

How do i need to proceed to do that..?
If possible and How to mention these two transaction managers in @Transactional annotation.